# .htaccess redirect loop error

Tags: htaccess, redirects

htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Remove www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

    RedirectMatch 301 /page_1 http://domain.com/segment_1/page_1
    RedirectMatch 301 /page_2 http://domain.com/segment_1/page_2
    RedirectMatch 301 /segment_1/page_x http://domain.com/segment_1/segment_2/page_x
</IfModule>
```

The last redirect works but the first two don't. (Error infinite loop).

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: First off, make sure you are testing by opening a fresh Private Browsing window (if you are using Chrome, or whatever your equivalent is). Most browsers cache 301 redirects (since they are supposed to be permanent), and this can display errors which may not actually exist.

Comment: Your code is correct so I'd agree with Adrian that it's some type of caching causing the issue.

Comment: As a test, have you moved one of the non-working redirects to the last position?

Comment: Nah. It doesn't work. No matter if private browsing, different computer or clearing cache/ disable ce-cache. Is there another way of doing 301 redirects?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the error (If anyone's intrested):

I must not write `RedirectMatch 301` instead I simply have to write `Redirect`.
So simple.

Comment: RedirectMatch = "contains" and Redirect = "starts with" in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I normally serve my redirects before my removal of index.php

Here's an example I know to work http://d.pr/n/1rQO